# SherlockFragmentActivity can not be resolved to a type

Tags: java, android, fragment

I currently am making an app where the Main activity opens up a google map. So i have it extending Fragment Activity. I also would like my app to have the action bar, but I would like to supply compatibility to Froyo(2.2).

I have android-support-v4.jar in my libs file but i don't know how to proceed. The extending of SherlockFragmentActivity can not be resolved to a type.

If it isn't SherlockFragmentActivity, then how do i do this? 
Either way a link to a tutorial or example would be helpful.

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap = null;
    SupportMapFragment mMapFragment;
.
.
.

}
```

EDIT:
Pretty sure I have actionbarsherlock as I went through the website's tutorial, etc. 
how do i know if it is imported(correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the SherlockFragmentActivity, assuming you have already added the ActionBarSherlock to your path.

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
```

Comment: it says this import cant be resolved, does this mean I imported it incorrectly?

Comment: It means that you have not the library in your classpath for this project.

Comment: Yes, that means you  did not add it to your project properly. I think the easiest method is to follow 1) under the "Including in your project" section found at http://actionbarsherlock.com/usage.html

Answer (score 2):

You will need to download and link the ActionBarSherlock library.

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sherlock is not part of android-support-v4.jar. You need to include Sherlock library to your project

Comment: I did add the library to my workspace and then to my project. Does this mean i did it incorrectly?